# Can you have or mimic within Visual Studio 2008 a Solution Level Pre and Post Build Events?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, post-build-event, pre-build-event

I would like to know if there is anyway to get the ability to have or at least mimic Pre and Post build events at the Solution level not just at the project level within Visual Studio 2008?

Therefor if possible I would like this functionality to be similar to how they work at the project level, except I only want them to run before building any projects and after building any projects.  For example to be a command-line style with Macro's if possible, however could be happy with being able to specify one or more CMD files to be run in order.

At worse case, can I create MSBuild .proj file and some how get it to be recognized by the sln file to run before anything and another after everything type of deal?

Any other suggestions to get similar behavior are welcomed as long as they are within the core VS2008 and MSBuild functionality. I cannot require the use of any add-ins or extensions to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the post-build, can you just do it in your lib/app project's post-build?

For the pre-build, you should be able to create a project and then set your Project dependencies such that everything depends on it. You can do the reverse for post-build if you don't want to use your lib/app's project's post-build.

**EDIT**: Of course, as pointed out, this won't actually work with the post-build. Durr.

Comment: I thought of this first and tried it before for posting. The problem even the "Empty Project" type is actually a Console application and would generate an EXE. It will not even build without an error out of the box, and having to hack away at it to make it go away.  I would love to have a REAL empty project type that has no .Net concepts associated with it and still had the pre/post build events. This also only solves the pre-build issue and not a post build even if it worked.

Comment: Did you try a Makefile project?

Comment: Yeah I ende dup going with the Makefile project even though it has the almost all the same draw backs as an Empty Project, with the exception that we can prevent any binary being built. So really I think the answer to the question is that you can't really do what I would like, but the best choices that seem available are Makefile Project and in some cases a Empty Project, and setting up the build dependecies in the Solution.  Feel free to modify your answer to reflect this, I am marking it as correct as it was the only answer and we talked through it in the comments.